# Compute a Quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA) in R assuming not normal data and missing information

Tags: r, normal-distribution, missing-data, discriminant-analysis, quadratic-form

In [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaIIr29Pj2g), the professor is saying that we can compute a QDA with missing data points and non-normal data (even if this assumption can be violated).

But the problem is that I don't know any function in R that can accommodate both the missing data points and the non-normal data. A QDA, from what I know is only interesting if you have heteroscedasticity. But it still need non-missing data points and normal data.

In the library `MASS`, they are saying:

> ```
> na.action 
> A function to specify the action to be taken if NAs are found. The default action is for the procedure to fail. An alternative is
> na.omit, which leads to rejection of cases with missing values on any
> required variable. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)
> ```

But actually, it means that we are just going to remove all the NAs. Right?

Do you know a way to compute a QDA that can use non-normal data and missing data points (NAs)?

For the NAs, I guess I just have to add `na.action = "na.exclude"`. Is that correct? If I want to predict the class of a data point but missing one information for a dimension, how can I predict the class?

Is the QDA in R a [Bayesian approximation as said here](https://rpubs.com/ryankelly/LDA-QDA) or it uses the frequentist approach?